# i should change I want to increase the number of news on the page with Php (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Currently, it shows 5 news on the page. But I would like to show 20 news, maybe even more. How can I change this with PHP. Thanks in advance to all those who support.

```
$perpage = $this->input->get('_pp') ? $this->input->get('_pp') :PERPAGE_5;
        $this->page = $this->input->get('per_page') ? intval($this->input->get('per_page')) : 0;
        $this->data->numOfContent = $this->news->getNews(false,false,TRUE);
        $this->link = site_url() . '/' . $this->urlString . '?_pp=' . $perpage;
        $this->data->news      = $this->news->getNews($perpage,$this->page);
```

Comment: Probably by replacing the constant `PERPAGE_5` with one that has the value `20` ...

Comment: Unclear why you were stuck with that, really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your $perpage variable. I think you are getting 5 in it.
Changing it will give you correct result.